# How to change/Set Background color of a cell [Row-based] in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

I have a table report in Power BI. I need to change/Set background color of a Cell based on another cell value as follows.

[image]

Eg: Row1 - Individual Cell's background color changes to green if corresponding Expected val is reached[85>70].

I found [Conditional formatting in tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) has this ability. I'm not able to get value of cell and make comparison to achieve color coding.

Please suggest on how to extract value of cell in Power BI to set/change background color.

Comment: Conditional formatting can do this, I've used it in the past. Where are you having issues?

Comment: Are the `Mark` columns separate in your data table or are they just pivoted that way in the visual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, PowerBI supports only column based formatting through option  *Conditional Formatting* 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting

Row-Based formatting option is not yet available. This feature can be suggested in POWERBI IDEAS forum.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas

PowerBI community to connect:

https://community.powerbi.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck! This feature was just added in the [May Power BI Desktop update](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-2018-feature-summary/).

Scroll down to the [conditional formatting section](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-2018-feature-summary/#conditionalFormatting) and it explains how you can format based on a different field.

---

Here's how you can use the feature I referenced.

First, create new calculated columns that take the difference between the expected value and the actual value. For example,

```
Diff3 = Marks[Mark3] - Marks[Expected Val]
```

(You'll need one of these columns for each mark column.)

Now use that column as the value to conditionally format the `Mark3` column:

[image: Conditional Formatting]

The other columns need to be formatted analogously.

---

Since they don't currently allow formulas in the rules, I don't think you can simplify this process much further just yet.

---

**Edit**

Note that if you unpivot the `MarkX` columns and the `Expected` column so the data is shaped like this:

[image: Unpivotted]

Then you only need a single `Diff` column:

```
Diff = Marks[Value] - LOOKUPVALUE(Marks[Value],
                          Marks[Name], Marks[Name],
                          Marks[Attribute], "Expected")
```

This also means you only need to conditionally format the single `Value` column instead of each `MarkX` column.

You can also not include the `Expected` column in the unpivot and get a table like this:

[image: Unpivotted 2]

This makes the `Diff` column simpler:

```
Diff = Marks[Value] - Marks[Expected]
```

But then it's difficult to include the `Expected` column in the matrix visual.

Comment: Oops! This feature is column based formatting. I need row based formatting as explained both in title and example.

Comment: It does work. I just didn't spell every step. Please see my edit.

Comment: Still its Column based not Row-based formatting yet

Comment: @Shalem Power BI visuals are built off of columns, not rows, and I've shown you how to conditionally format to match your example. What is it that you are asking for at this point?

Comment: My requirement is of Row-based formatting, not column based. I know PowerBI Visuals are of column based.

Comment: If your `Mark1` through `Mark5` are five different columns in your data table, then what you are asking for cannot be done.

Comment: This is still not row based formatting. Perfect row based formatting would be based on Diff3 value in that row not based on Sum of Diff3

Comment: @be_good_do_good The Sum of Diff3 is precisely what's shown in that row of the matrix visual though. Since Power BI works on a columnar data model, row based formatting is not possible except as the workaround I've shown. Fortunately, this is perfectly sufficient to produce the visual result requested even if you disagree with the semantics.